# How to get ps output with headers

Tags: linux, debian, ps

The question is basic, How to get output of `ps` with headers in Linux.

Linux details:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
```

I can get it with `ps -ef | { head -1; grep query; }`, but that is lot of text. When looking at docs of `ps` using `man ps`, I can see there is one option `--headers`, but using that also does not give headers:

```
>~$ ps aux --headers | grep grep
user  24082  0.0  0.0   6656   628 pts/0    S+   12:59   0:00 grep grep
```

Also tried option `h` with the command:

```
~$ ps auxh  | grep grep
user  25982  0.0  0.0   6656   624 pts/0    S+   13:14   0:00 grep grep
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I am not sure `headers` is needed.
2. the headers are printed, but are filtred out by grep.

**awk** solution

```
ps aux --headers| awk 'NR==1 || /awk/ '
```

- `NR==1` keep first line
- `||` or
- `/awk/` line with awk

**egrep** solution

```
ps aux | egrep '^USER|grep'
```

- either `^USER` USER string at start of line
- or `grep` string

**ps** solution

If string match a program, you can use `-C` option (along with needed fields)

```
ps -C sshd -o stime,etime,args
```

Comment: Yes, correct, missed that it get filtered out by the grep. Thanks